# Encoding problem AFTER using listings

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

I'm trying to insert some code in a document, and I'm using the package listings for that. I'm well aware that inserting special utf8 characters requires some precautions that can be set with \lstset and the literate parameter.

It works, except the the "regular" texts that follows the block of code. I also tried with listingsutf8, inline or with \lstinputlisting. It still fails.

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=c++,
        keywordstyle=\bf,
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        tabsize=2,
        inputencoding=utf8,
        extendedchars=true,
        literate={é}{{\'{e}}}1
        }

\begin{document}

Accentué %works fine : document in utf8

\begin{lstlisting}code working fine
int i = 2; //accentué 
\end{lstlisting}

Accentué %fails (if this line is removed, the code compiles)

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid that ?

Comment: Just use encoding `utf8` not `utf8x`.  Incidentally, the language option to babel is now `french` not `francais`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `utfx8` encoding, that has many issues.  For French it is sufficient to use `utf8`.  Incidentally, the `babel` option is now called `french`, not `francais` which is likely to disappear soon.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=c++,
        keywordstyle=\bf,
        frame=single,
        numbers=left,
        tabsize=2,
        inputencoding=utf8,
        extendedchars=true,
        literate={é}{{\'{e}}}1
        }

\begin{document}

Accentué

\begin{lstlisting}
  code working fine
  int i = 2; //accentué
\end{lstlisting}

Accentué

\end{document}
```